# NSOperationQueue currentQueue not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to run `AFURLConnectionOperation` seen below on the currentQueue as I want to keep my main thread free for user interatoin, however nothing happens when I call mainQeue.

However if I call the same `AFURLConnectionOperation` on mainQueue it works perfectly.

Pleas see following code

```
// Send Batch
        NSArray *operations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:mutableOperations progressBlock:^(NSUInteger numberOfFinishedOperations, NSUInteger totalNumberOfOperations) {
            NSLog(@"%lu of %lu complete", (unsigned long)numberOfFinishedOperations, (unsigned long)totalNumberOfOperations);
        } completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
            // check batch response
            NSError *error;
            for (AFHTTPRequestOperation *op in operations) {
                if (op.isCancelled){
                    return ;
                }
                if (op.responseObject){
                    // Current JSON Batch complete
                    NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:op.request.HTTPBody options:kNilOptions error:&error];
                    // Update sent_flag using current chunk
                    [[SyncModel sharedInstance] updateSentFlag:jsonObject];
                }
                if (op.error){
                    error = op.error;
                    NSLog(@"Error == %@", error);
                }
            }
        }];
```

Then finally I call one or the other of the following code

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO]; // this works
[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperations:operations waitUntilFinished:NO]; // this dose not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is

> You can use this method from within a running operation object to get a reference to the operation queue that started it. Calling this method from outside the context of a running operation typically results in nil being returned.

So,I guess,if you log `[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]`,it is nil

If you want a new queue,use

```
[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
```

Comment: So if i create my own NSOperationQueue that won't run on the main thread?

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem you have, the operations is async,it will not freeze main thread.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the operation on queue, if the operation doesn't start eventually then there are two ways to get them executed.

1. Using wait block, for example during unit test using XCTest framework, use

   ```
   XCTestExpectation *expectation1 = [self    expectationWithDescription:@"ExtractColorsInternal function call on     NSOperationQueue"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   [expectation1 fulfill];
   });

   [self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:1000 handler:^(NSError *error) {
   if (error != nil) {
       NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
   }
   }];
   ```
2. call CFRunLoopRun(), which would execute the present operation in current queue succesfully